# How Do i read in lines from files or keyboard input into a dynamic string array?

Tags: data-structures

so its been a long day and this might be trivial but I am not landing my thought on it. but I have a string dynamic array data structure. and my project is to basically check for palindromes. read in a file or input from keyboard until end of line character each line and check to see if that line is a palindrome. I have the part wehre it checks the string if its a palindrome or not done. and the data structure works fine.

but How do I read in data from a file  or keyboard and insert them character by character into the dynamic string array data structure without making a clumsy temporary variable with large constant size?.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: am using c with only basic libraries